# How to number only labeled equations?

Tags: equations, cross-referencing, numbering

I'm writing all my equations with

```
\begin{equation} ... \end{equation}
```

so all of them are numbered but only some of them are labeled. I don't want all of them with numbers but only the labeled ones.

Since I have a real big document I don't wanna do this manually using * for all the others. How can I do this automatically?

Comment: Since it seems that the answer by **Bernard** wasn't useful to you, please provide a [minimal (non-)working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) showing the issue. Only then we can really help you.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You have a possibility, with the `mathtools` package (that loads `amsmath`, so it's useless to load the latter): write

```
\mathtoolsset{showonlyrefs,showmanualtags}
```

in your preamble, and only the `referenced` equations will be numbered (use `\eqref`). It's not exactly what you ask (number `labelled` equations), but you can try to make ‘fake references’ at the very end of your document.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I tried that and equations are referred non of them have numbers

Comment: You mean non-referred equations have no number, I suppose? Your comment isn't quite clear to me.

Comment: I mean, I have numbers in my text referring to equations but my equations don't have numbers anymore

Comment: Could you post a Minimal Working Example?

Comment: Btw, did you think of using `eqref` rather than `ref`?

Comment: I was not using eqref. Now I'm using eqref and it works perfectly! Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

No warranty. `;-)`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{etoolbox}


\makeatletter
\newif\ifdavid@number
\preto\equation{\david@numberfalse}
\preto\endequation{\ifdavid@number\else\notag\fi}
\patchcmd\label@in@display{\@empty}{\@empty\david@numbertrue}{}{}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
Text
\begin{equation}
\text{this has a number}\label{a}
\end{equation}
text
\begin{equation}
\text{this hasn't}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This is awesome but it failed for 'aligns' and for some reason links in my document don't lead to the right places anymore (I'm using \usepackage{hyperref})

Comment: @David You just mentioned `equation`, didn't you? I can't guess what you're using in your document. Besides, do you really mean to number only the labeled equations in an `align`?